# C++ std::future<bool> in a recursive function

Tags: c++11, promise, std

Considering the following, would it be possible to recurse into the function? I don’t think std::move would work, as on unwinding the variable would be gone, how would you approach something like this?

```
auto TestFunc(std::future<bool> promisedExit
        , int max
        , const char* pszTesting)
{
  if (promisedExit.get()) { // The calling thread will set this to cause this thread to exit.
     return false;
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
  if (max != 10) {
     TestFunc(std::move(promisedExit), max++, pszTesting); // Issue is here with std::move(...)
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

To clarify, I'm not sure if i can pass on the future without moving it? i.e having the future valid to check with each recursion?

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"? `promisedExit` is an empty future if you move from it

Comment: Exactly, so what I'm looking for is a way to pass on the future without moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`shared_future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future), not a (unique) `future`. You can get the initial one by `share()`ing the `future` you start with.

```
auto TestFunc(std::shared_future<bool> promisedExit
        , int max
        , const char* pszTesting)
{
  if (promisedExit.get()) { // The calling thread will set this to cause this thread to exit.
     return false;
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
  if (max != 10) {
     TestFunc(promisedExit, max++, pszTesting);
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Giving this a try! :)